# Can a transformer run on low voltage ac?

Tags: transformer, low-voltage

Can a 0.5 VAC power supply be stepped up to a higher voltage with a transformer?

Comment: 0.5Vac power supply? Quite extraordinary. Anyway, if you have a 50/60Hz step down power transformer with any voltage ratio, you can see that applying 0.5Vac/50Hz to its secondary will give you a higher voltage on primary. For example, apply 0.5Vac to a 220-to-24 transformer's secondary. You'll get nearly 5Vac on primary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The transformer will consume a bit of power and the available output current will be reduced, of course, in keeping with conservation of energy.

So if you had 0.1A at 0.5VAC you could get less than 10mA at 5VAC.

In general, to be optimal, a transformer should be designed specifically for the voltages, currents and frequency or frequencies involved.

Transformers get more difficult at extremely low and extremely high frequencies.

Comment: I am using a motor with the 0.5VAC output. Will it still work?

Comment: A brushed permanent magnet DC  motor will give you pulsating DC rather than AC. It still could probably be made to 'work' with AC coupling.

Answer (score 0):

In theory ANY AC signal can be stepped up (or down) using a transformer.  However, an AC supply of only 0.5 V seems extraordinarily unlikely to have enough power to make stepping up practical.  The very unlikly possibility of a 0.5VAC supply makes this question extremely doubtful.

Comment: Depends whether this is a power application or a signal application. For example, some audio microphone prramps use an input transformer to give voltage gain from a dynamic microphone. We are talking about  input voltage levels in the very-low millivolt range.

Comment: I took @WasabiPickle's word for it that the source is a "power supply" and not some sort of AC (audio?) signal?

Comment: An ultrasound PZT driver?

Comment: It is a brushed motor.